# Word/ phrase for : 'to uplift/ enhance one's mental level/ creativity/ knowledge'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking out for a word   or a short phrase(<15 chars.) that somewhat conveys : 'to uplift/ enhance one's mental level/ creativity/ knowledge/ skills'. 'To take one's mental level to the next level & transform oneself into more intelligent being'. **Simplest** & shorter words/phrases are more preferable.

Comment: Extra points if we don't use vowels?

Comment: Er... to learn?

Comment: `to learn` denotes sort of prerequisite action for improvement, perhaps..

Answer (score 3):

A formal word to express this idea is **edify**, meaning *instruct or improve (someone) morally or intellectually.*

Answer (score 0):

That's usually called `brain training`.  For example, there's a company called [lumosity](http://www.lumosity.com/) that sells on-line brain training games.

In New Age circles, people who have achieved higher levels of spiritual awareness are often described as `evolved`.

What about `educate` ... or does education have a bad reputation these days?

(N.B. I do **not** endorse lumosity's products.  I'm just using it as an example.)